# Have trouble in fetching the required data from DB

Tags: java, jdbc, collections

I have a table like this.

```
AreaId  LineId  ShapePointno    x   y
1             0    0            2   3
1             0    1            2   5
1             0    2            3   8
1             1    0            2   6
1             1    1            3   2
```

Before, getting into the problem, I would explain on the fields. 
A line Id 0 belonging to `AreaId1` 1 has 3 shape points numbered as 0,1 and 2. Its x and y corresponds to its co-ordinate positions.

With this background, let me put the problem in hand.

I need to fetch these records and bring  it to **java**.

While bringing in, I need to have it as a block of shape points for a line. (i.e) 1st 3 rows as one block and next 2 in a different block. The reason behind this is I need to modify x & y values and the modification function expects the following parameters.

```
  i)AreaID, LineId, A 2D array of its shape points).
```

Here is what I have tried out.

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/task4DB?"
              + "user=root&password=123");
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select Distinct AreaId from TableName")
    ResultSet r1=st.executeQuery();
   while (r1.next())
    {
    int id = r1.getInt("AreaId");
    PreparedStatement st1 = con.prepareStatement("select Distinct LineId where AreaId = id")
    ResultSet r2=st1.executeQuery();
    while (r2.next())
    {
      int lineid = r2.getInt("LineId");
      PreparedStatement st2 = con.prepareStatement("select x,y  where AreaId = id and LineId = lineid")
      ResultSet r3=st2.executeQuery();
      int size = 0;
      int [][]xy = new int[r3.getCount()][r3.getCount()]
       while (r3.next())
      {

       xy[size][0] = r3.getInt("x");
       xy[size][1] = r3.getInt("y");
       size++;
      }
     callShapePointConv(id,lineId,xy);
    }
 }
```

I don't get the expected results rather it shows junk values/

Please help me out.

Also, is there any other  better alternate available rather than three while loops?

Kindly Help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to insert an image. I am sorry as my table structure is not aligned as I wanted.

Comment: @TAsk: Ya its a typo. Edited now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just quessing here but your selects are flawed in many ways.

```
select Distinct LineId where AreaId = id
```

First, where is you `FROM` Table declaration.
Second: Did you want to fetch the distinct list of LineId based on the previously retrieved id?

If so, your parameterized select should look like this:

```
select Distinct LineId from table_2 where AreaId = ?
```

But what you really should look up is how to use joins in select statements.

**Update**

You code does not make sense any more.

First you get the unique AreaIds. --> 1

Then you get the unique LineIds --> 0,1

Then you select all elements from the table, where

```
(1) while: AreaId = 1 
   and L
   (2) while:
          (loop 1) lineId = 0 
          (loop 2) lineId = 1
```

This will ultimately return the table content :)

Maybe, this can help you:

This will group the x and y, based on the areaId and lineId as lists of values.

```
SELECT
    AreaId,
    LineId,
    GROUP_CONCAT(table.x),
    GROUP_CONCAT(table.y)
FROM
    `table`
GROUP BY
    AreaId,
    LineId
ORDER BY
    table.ShapePointno
```

Result:

```
AreaId LineId GROUP_CONCAT(table.x)  GROUP_CONCAT(table.y)
1      0      "2,2,3"                "3,5,8"
1      1      "2,3"                  "6,2"
```

Comment: Yes Group_COncat is something I was not aware. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I found it - 
At line number 14 you are executing st1.executeQuery() but it should be st2.execute query

I have commented your line and added the correct one.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/task4DB?"
              + "user=root&password=123");
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select Distinct AreaId from TableName")
    ResultSet r1=st.executeQuery();
   while (r1.next())
{
int id = r1.getInt("AreaId");
 PreparedStatement st1 = con.prepareStatement("select Distinct LineId where AreaId = id")
 ResultSet r2=st1.executeQuery();
 while (r2.next())
{
 int lineid = r2.getInt("LineId");
 PreparedStatement st2 = con.prepareStatement("select x,y  where AreaId = id and LineId = lineid")
 //ResultSet r3=st1.executeQuery();
  ResultSet r3 = st2.executeQuery();
int size = 0;
int [][]xy = new int[r3.getCount()][r3.getCount()]
 while (r3.next())
{

 xy[size][0] = r3.getInt("x");
 xy[size][1] = r3.getInt("y");
 size++;
}
callShapePointConv(id,lineId,xy);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. Do you feel any other approach in achieving my need? This idea would keep reading the Db more than once. I wish to have a mechanism of reading the table once and performing the needed operation.

Comment: Ah well if the table have well designed primary key and foreign key relation then you should think of join query hence you have to execute single query to get the data of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Java code, You can reduce complexity of database design in following manner,

**Table_1:**

```
AreaLineId(FK) ShapePointno   x     y
    0              0          2     3
    0              1          2     5
    0              2          3     8
    1              0          2     6
    1              1          3     2
```

**Table_2 :**

```
AreaLineId   AreaId   LineId    
   0           1        0    
   1           1        1
```

Now query will be,

```
select x,y from table_1 where AreaLineId = id;
```

and another select wapper query to get id from table_2 will do the job with less complexity.

Comment: Hi Kishan: The table is an input from 3rd part vendor and I should accept it as I get :) So ths wont workout for me.

Comment: "Is there any other better alternate available rather than three while loops ?" thats why I suggested this answer...for better one.